# Convert last three digits from time fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to convert the last three digits to `000` from `2013-11-22 13:21:35.297`

The data type is `datetime`.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `select substring(date_column, 1, 19)`

Comment: table account column logdatetime

Comment: it also replace seconds with millisecond

Answer (score 2):

[`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)/[`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is the usual way I use to round a datetime value down to a particular granularity:

```
select DATEADD(second,DATEDIFF(second,'20010101','2013-11-22T13:21:35.297')
                                     ,'20010101')
```

For most levels of granularity, you can just use `0` instead of `'20010101'` but unfortunately, that causes an overflow when we're working with `second`s and with contemporary dates. `'20010101'` can just be any relatively nearby fixed date.

---

As an update, it would be:

```
UPDATE account
SET logdatetime = DATEADD(second,DATEDIFF(second,'20010101',logdatetime)
                                                ,'20010101')
```

Comment: I need to update bulk data, please suggest for table and column based solution. Table account and column logdatetime- data type datetime

Comment: for select on based table and column?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server versions 2008 or higher, this works very well. The key is that the datetime2 datatype is specified with a zero precision, thus decimal seconds are truncated.

```
Declare @chk datetime = '2013-11-22 13:21:35.297';
```

`select convert(datetime,convert(datetime2(0),@chk));`